# MATLAB: Collapse code cells in MATLAB's editor

Tags: matlab

I have recently started to use the code cell function in MATLAB's editor and I find it great, however it would be very useful if I could collapse the code cells. 
I assume this is possible like you can collapse for-loops in MATLAB, however I have not been able to figure out how to do it yet.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I've never been able to figure this out either  I've been using Matlab for about 6 years now.  But then, sometimes I use Emacs for editing my M-files.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: An area where MATLAB has really improved is the IDE. I like the enhanced *editor highlighting* in R2010b. See http://www.mathworks.com/videos/matlab/variable-and-function-highlighting-in-r2010b.html?type=shadow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a post from 'Mike on the MATLAB Desktop' about [folding cells](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/06/15/fold-whatever-you-want-using-cells/).

Comment: +1: like I commented, I'd never stumbled across this.  Thanks @zellus.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Turned out the solution was very simple :-)

Comment: In newer versions of MATLAB preferences are in execution environment->home ribbon-> environment tab-> preferences